# jquery animation is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

my jquery script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#tt").mouseover(function () {
    $("#aa").animate({
      padding: "5px 0 5px 100px",
      backgroundColor: "#7EEFF7",
    });
  });

  $("#tt").mouseout(function () {
    $("#aa").animate({
      padding: "0"
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

my HTML code is like this

```
<li id="tt">
  <a id="aa" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'new_user'; ?>">New User</a>
</li>
```

in the browser when i move my mouse over this it is animating more than once.  why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.stop()` to clear the animation queue before starting a new animation.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#tt").mouseover(function () {
    $("#aa").stop().animate({
      padding: "5px 0 5px 100px",
      backgroundColor: "#7EEFF7",
    });
  });

  $("#tt").mouseout(function () {
    $("#aa").stop().animate({
      padding: "0"
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You just put animate begin when mouse enter a DOM with ID #tt.

In this case, if #tt does not have WIDTH, you can mouse over and out in white space. Test it to mouse over and out 3 times or more. jQuery will run the animate 3 times.

Solution:
Add css width in your #tt. It will be work as you wish or use stop like Rajaprabhu mentioned it.

Comment: Thank you. both answers are useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complete:function() in animate function so when the animation is complete return to original value

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#tt" ).mouseover(function() {
        $( "#aa" ).animate({
            padding: "5px 0 5px 100px",
            backgroundColor: "#7EEFF7",
        }, {
            complete: function() {
            $( "#aa" ).css("padding","0px");
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```